# Return webpage having a plot in Flask

Tags: python, html, matplotlib, flask

I have this route in my flask app which takes a file name and sprint number from the user through a form (burndown_form.html). It calls a function "burndown_gen" using these params which returns a python data frame. I need to display a plot based on this dataframe on a web page after the user clicks the submit button on "burndown_form.html". How do I do this?

```
@app.route('/burndown', methods=['GET','POST'])
def output_burndown_chart():
    if request.method == "POST":
        sprint_num = request.form['sprint_number']
        file_name = request.form['file_name']
        dir_name = "./files"
        file_path = os.path.join(dir_name, file_name)
        df_b = burndown_gen(file_path,sprint_num)
        df_b.plot.line(x='Date',y='Story Points Left',figsize=(10,5))
    return render_template('burndown_form.html')
```

burndown_form.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Sprint Velocity</h1>
<form action="{{ url_for('output_burndown_chart') }}" method="post">
    <label for="file_name">File Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="file_name"><br>
    <label for="sprint_number">Sprint Number:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="sprint_number"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to store the plot as a figure in the static folder of your Flask app folder structure and then display it on using an image reference in your html template. Something like this:

```
fig = df_b.plot.line(x='Date',y='Story Points Left',figsize=(10,5)).get_figure()
fig.savefig('static/plot.png')
```

However, this limits your flexibility to customize your chart as you need to convert it into an image file. Therefore, the better way to do it would be to use something like `chart.js` in your html template by passing the data frame.

You'd need to convert your data frame to something that's JSON serializable, since python data frames can't be serializable into JSON format. Since you have two columns, you could split them into two lists like this.

```
date_list = df_b['Date'].tolist() 
sp_list = df_b['SPs_Left'].tolist()
```

And then pass it like this.

```
return render_template('output_burndown.html', date_list=date_list, sp_list=sp_list)
```

You'd then need to convert your lists to JSON using the `tojson` command and use those as the data for your graph.

```
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: {{ date_list|tojson }},
                    datasets: [{
                        label: "burndown",
                        data: {{ sp_list|tojson }},
                        borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                    }]
                },
                options: {}
            });
        </script>
```

More on `chart.js` can be found [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/)